# Scroll to Top with Animate as Percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently tried to make the scroll to top with animate jquery. Everything seems ok. But I need to do as with percentage.
For Example
`scrollTop` is `100%` then it scroll's 100% . I am not sure. Right now i believe it is in pixel. How to use percentage in animate function of jquery, something like `scrollTop:100%`
I tried that but i get console error.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYFNG/)**

```
 $('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function () {
                          alert("reached top");
                        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, as you found, `animate` requires a pixel value, you'll have to take the height of the element ([`innerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) is probably best), apply the percentage to it (`Math.round(height * percentage / 100)` assuming a `percentage` value like `70` for 70%), and then use that number of pixels.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the scrollTop height is in pixels. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2):

> An integer indicating the new position to set the scroll bar to.

You would have to calculate the percentage yourself:

```
$('#spnTop').on("click",function(){
    var percentageToScroll = 0.50;
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollAmount = Math.floor(documentHeight * percentageToScroll);
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount }, 'slow', function () {
                          alert("reached top");
    });
});
```